# Dictionary raises KeyError on lookup even though key is actually set

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, keyerror

When I attempt to print a dictionary (or its `__dict__`), a KeyError is raised. The dict is a mapping from `MyClass` instances to floats and ints.
It would be too lengthy to share the source code of `MyClass`.

```
d = dict()
d[MyClass()] = 10.023
d[MyClass()] = 1.023
d[MyClass()] = 8
print(d)
Out[16]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\[...]\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

[...]

    618             p.pretty(key)
    619             p.text(': ')
--> 620             p.pretty(obj[key])
    621         p.end_group(step, end)
    622     return inner

KeyError: <MyClass.subclass instance>
```

Also the following raises KeyError:

```
for key in d:
    print(d[key])
```

Although some of the values are printed correctly before an error is raised. It seems to have trouble looking up some specific keys.

I think this is pretty weird too:

```
In [19]: [a in d for a in d]
Out[19]: [False, True, False, True, False]
```

Finally:

```
list(d) # works fine, just like d.keys() and d.values()
Out[19]: [<MyClass.subclass instance>,<MyClass.subclass instance>,<MyClass.subclass instance>,...]
d[list(d)[0]] # works fine
Out[20]: 10.023
d[list(d)[1]] # raises KeyError
list(d)[1] in d # returns False
list(d)[0] in d # returns True
```

I checked:
 - all keys have different hashes
 - list(d) contains no duplicates
 - list(d) instances which are correctly looked up have no noticeable difference (some are even instances of the same class)
 - List item

I cannot think of an explanation to this behaviour. It only manifested today.
I recently made some changes in the file structure of the module containing `MyClass`. Before: `MyClass` subclasses in the same file as `MyClass` definition.
After: `MyClass` subclasses in individual files in the same directory.
I cannot see how this could affect any of that, but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances this should not happen.

However you can violate the dictionary contract that the keys must be immutable with respect to equality and hash. Because if the hash changes the objects cannot be found anymore.

> ## [Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
>
> [...]
>
> A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.

To demonstrate what can happen when you use mutable objects with a hash-function that depends on values: Consider this class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.value
```

And this little snippet:

```
>>> t1 = Test(1)
>>> d = {}
>>> d[t1] = 10
>>> t1.value = 2  # t1's hash also changes at this point
>>> d[t1]
KeyError: <__main__.Test object at 0x0000020FCA5AD748>
```

This is of course overly simplified but I suspect that something like this happens in your code. I propose you monitor changes to the values that are relevant for `__hash__` and `__eq__` during the program execution.

Comment: yes! good one. But does that also explain how all keys remain accessible in the d.keys() method? that really confused me.

Comment: Indeed a component of the hash that was not supposed to change was being changed. Bug found! Thanks

Comment: @user3886973 The key-value pair is still in the dictionary. It's just that lookup calculates the "current" hash and checks that hash against the hash that was calculated when the key was inserted in the dictionary. If that changes the lookup fails. During iteration and `.keys` it just returns **all** stored key-value pairs (regardless of hash).

Comment: @user3886973 I'm glad the answer lead you in the correct direction and thank you for accepting the answer. Please don't forget to also [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all answers that you consider helpful/useful.

Answer (score 0):

`d = dict(MyClass()=10.023, MyClass()=1.023, MyClass()=8)` is not the correct syntax of creating a dict. When I try to run it as follows

```
class A:
    pass

d = dict(A() = 10.023, A() = 1.023, A() = 8)
print(d)
```

I get the exception

```
    d = dict(A() = 10.023, A() = 1.023, A() = 8)
            ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

a correct example which tries to do something similar is, where I make a list of tuples `(classobject, value)` then convert it to a dict

```
class A:
    pass

d = dict([(A(),10.023), (A(),1.023), (A(),8)])
print(d)
```

The output will be

```
{<__main__.A object at 0x103072ba8>: 10.023, <__main__.A object at 0x103072be0>: 1.023, <__main__.A object at 0x103072c88>: 8}
```

Also `list(d)` gives you a list of keys, as you already saw in your example, and then when you do `d[list(d)[0]]`, you are getting the first key, and then get the value of the first key.

For the last two statements, they will return true if you follow my naming convention, also the updated statement in your question works for me too.

```
class A:
    pass

d = dict([(A(),10.023), (A(),1.023), (A(),8)])

#Print list of keys
print(list(d))
#[<__main__.A object at 0x102a72ba8>, <__main__.A object at 0x102a72be0>, <__main__.A object at 0x102a72c88>]

#Value of first key
print(d[list(d)[0]])
#10.023

#Value of second key
print(d[list(d)[1]])
#1.023

#Checks if second key is present in list of keys, which is True
print(list(d)[1] in d )
#True

#Checks if first key is present in list of keys, which is True
print(list(d)[0] in d )
#True
```

**Update**: Your new updated syntax also works for me if I use a simpler class

```
class A:
    pass

d = dict()
d[A()] = 10.023
d[A()] = 1.023
d[A()] = 8

print(d)
#{<__main__.A object at 0x101f72be0>: 10.023, <__main__.A object at 0x101f72c88>: 1.023, <__main__.A object at 0x101f7def0>: 8}


for key in d:
    print(d[key])
#10.023
#1.023
#8
```

Comment: Updated my answer, all examples you showed work for me if you follow the convention I used in my answer, please check @user3886973 ?

Comment: Also your updated code in the question also works for me @user3886973